# Define an enumeration function

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to understand the enumeration of sets, and I have a question with no solutions.

Define an enumeration function for the set S = { 1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, ... }

From what I grasp of it, the set looks as if it's just the set of all positive natural numbers, but I'm not sure how to "enumerate" it.

Any help would be good, thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that this is a trick question? $S$ is indeed the set of natural numbers, and if someone asked me to enumerate the natural numbers I would just give $f(n)=n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*:

If $n$ is even, add $1$. If it is odd, substract $1$.

Comment: I don't know how I managed to miss that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, starting with $n=0$:
$$f(n)=n+(-1)^n$$